# Sendmail error 550 5.1.1 "user unknown"

Tags: sendmail, redhat

I have configured sendmail server on RHEL 6. I followed following steps:

1. check ip, hostname, make entry in /etc/hosts
2. edit /etc/mail/sendmail.mc     comment line no 116 using dnl
3. m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
4. start/restart the sendmail service

I have created two local users user1 and user2. Now my problem is, if I sent mail from root to "user1", it works properly. But trying to sent mail from root to user2, it returns error 550 user unknown.

I checked `/var/log/maillog`, it gives stat=user unknown.

I already read all the posts related to same question, but still I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Does user2 name contain any uppercase (AB...) letters?

Comment: No, it justs same as it as user1 , I sent mail from root to user2 , mail -v user2@server , it returns error , sender ok but user unknown.

Comment: Does username contain any non-USASCII characters or characters beyond letteres and digits?  What is reported by `sendmail -d60.5 -d27.2 -bv user2` executed by root? [Is user2 name rewritten before the check?]

Comment: thank you for this command `sendmail -d60.5 -d27.2 -bv user2`,

Comment: it returns `alias(USER2) ,user2 unknown`. So i just simply modify the username, like `usermod -l testuser user2`.and now it works fine,mails are delivered to testuser. but i am not able to understand why actually previous error occurs,what is the role of alias here

Comment: sendmail can be mis-configured in **many** ways.  I will not try to give more guesses without seeing **exact** results of debug command e.g. in standard configuration alias lookup should be made on lowercased string [alias(user2)]